# How to test if there is only default buffer open?

Tags: vim

I'm writing a plugin that loads sessions only if no buffers have been open. So far I'm [testing vs argc](https://github.com/wting/gitsessions.vim/blob/master/plugin/gitsessions.vim#L54).

```
if (argc() != 0)
    return
endif
```

This works fine if I pass in arguments from the command line: `vim file1`

However, the problem is that I have some scripts that wrap around vim:

```
function foo {
    vim file1
}

$ foo
```

In the latter case, `argc` is empty and thus the above if condition fails.

How do you test if vim was invoked with only the default buffer open?

Comment: I don't see the behaviour you are describing. In the simple test I did `argc()` contained the right number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass files to Vim, that will be reflected in `argc` (also when you wrap the Vim invocation). Rather, the corner case is launching Vim with an edit command, e.g. `vim -c "edit foo"`. If you need to detect that, you need to check two things:

- the current buffer is the default blank buffer
- no other text buffers have been loaded

Here's a set of functions to implement that:

```
function! IsBlank( bufnr )
    return (empty(bufname(a:bufnr)) &&
    \ getbufvar(a:bufnr, '&modified') == 0 &&
    \ empty(getbufvar(a:bufnr, '&buftype'))
    \)
endfunction

function! ExistOtherBuffers( targetBufNr )
    return ! empty(filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'buflisted(v:val) && v:val != a:targetBufNr'))
endfunction

function! IsEmptyVim()
    let l:currentBufNr = bufnr('')
    return IsBlank(l:currentBufNr) && ! ExistOtherBuffers(l:currentBufNr)
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1):

The best I could come up with was to write a function.  I thought bufnr('$') would do it but it lists that highest loaded buffer number.  The bufnr('$') function returns 1 even though I have not opened a file (simply launched vim).  Also buffers can be unloaded with :bw, which does not change what bufnr('$') returns.

Anyway this is the function:

```
function! NumBuffers()
    let rc = 0
    for idx in range(bufnr('$'))
        if bufloaded(idx)
            let rc += 1
        endif
    endfor
    return rc
endfunction
```